# iPhone 4s Can't turn on WiFi button because no response

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, backup

I haven't backed up my phone in almost a year. Now today I had a strange issue appear that the phone froze for hours and I couldn't do anything at all. Now it mysteriously unfroze and i'm afraid that if I don't back it up i'll eventually have to restore it and I'll lose everything.

To back up the iPhone 4s, wi-fi needs to be on however, the wi-fi button is off and it won't let me click wi-fi on. The button doesn't respond. The button hasn't responded in months. What can I do to turn on wi-fi and how do I get the button to respond? Did I accidentally click something somewhere that makes the Wi-fi button never respond?

Comment: What happens when you go to Settings app > WiFi? Is the button at the top turned on?

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't use wi-fi to backup. Use a USB cable. Even if wi-fi backup is enabled, you can always plug your iPhone into your computer and initiate a backup via USB. Plus, it is much faster.